# The name of dual concept of evaluation map

Tags: functions, terminology

Given a collection of sets $\{Y_\alpha: \alpha \in A \}$ for an index set $A$. For each $\alpha \in A$, let $f_\alpha: X \to Y_\alpha$ be a function. The map $f: X \to \prod_{\alpha \in A} Y_\alpha$ defined by
$$
    f(x) = \prod_{\alpha \in A} f_\alpha(x) = (f_\alpha(x))_{\alpha \in A}
$$

is called the `evaluation map` where $\prod$ denotes the Cartesian product. For each $\alpha \in A$, let $g_\alpha: Y_\alpha \to Z$ be a function. Let the map $g: \coprod_{\alpha \in A} Y_\alpha \to Z$ be defined by
$$
    g(x) = g_\alpha(x) \text{ if } x \in Y_\alpha
$$
where $\coprod$ denotes the disjoint union. What is the name of this map?

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming that by $\prod_{\alpha\in A}f_\alpha(x)$ you mean the $A$-tuple $(f_\alpha(x))_{\alpha\in A}$.

The disjoint union and the Cartesian product are the categorical [sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) and [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)) in the category of sets, respectively. They can both be regarded as [functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) from the [product category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_category) $\prod_{\alpha\in A}\textbf{Set}$ to $\textbf{Set}$. Functors map both objects and morphisms. The evaluation map $f$ is the morphism in  $\textbf{Set}$ to which the product functor maps the $A$-tuple $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ (which is a morphism in $\prod_{\alpha\in A}\textbf{Set}$). Analogously, your map $g$ is the morphism in $\textbf{Set}$ to which the sum functor (i.e. the disjoint union functor) maps the $A$-tuple $(g_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$. Thus, you could refer to it as the disjoint union of the $g_\alpha$. I don’t know whether there’s a more specific name for it than that, like “evaluation map” for the product.

Comment: I would prefer to call it the (co)product pairing. I think (co)product map should be reserved for the situation where we have really used the functor structure i.e. taken $X\to Y,A\to B$ and obtained some $X\times A\to Y\times B$ or $X\sqcup A\to Y\sqcup B$. In this case, we instead have some $X\to A,B$ and the induced $X\to A\times B$, or dually some $A\to X,B\to X$ and the induced $A\sqcup B\to X$, which isn't using the functor structure but rather the universal property